# VB: Gridview edit and update - update is not updating the database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview in VB. I have 2 updates that need to happen:

1st is a checkbox which is a simple boolean update, this works perfectly. 
2nd is using the out of the box edit on a gridview and allow editing on a single column (Comments). This when clicking edit reveals an input box that I can fill in. upon saving it no errors, but also no committing the text to the database seems to happen.

I suspect I need to create another update within the APSX? But I am unable to do this at the ASPX level if I try and add another UpdateCommand, it will complain about duplicates.

I am very new to this if you couldn't tell.

Here is my code.

default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="BusinessSignUps.WebForm1" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.OleDB" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
<title>Business Signups</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/styles.css">
  </head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

</div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="BusinessSignUps" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="ID" PageSize="20" >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="False" >
               <ControlStyle CssClass="MyLinkButtons" />
            </asp:CommandField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelect" runat="server" Checked="false" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" Visible="false" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="contact" HeaderText="Support Called"  ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Year" HeaderText="Year"  ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Week" HeaderText="Week"  ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="account_id" HeaderText="account id" SortExpression="account_id" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="product_name" HeaderText="product Name" SortExpression="product_name" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="begin_date" HeaderText="Begin Date" SortExpression="begin_date" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="begin_request_date" HeaderText="Begin Request Date" SortExpression="begin_request_date" ReadOnly="True"  Visible="false"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="billing_country_code" HeaderText="Country Code" SortExpression="billing_country_code" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="region" HeaderText="Region" SortExpression="region" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="billing_zip" HeaderText="ZIP" SortExpression="billing_zip" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="clear_name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="clear_name" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="clear_lower_email" HeaderText="Email Address" SortExpression="clear_lower_email" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Territory" HeaderText="Territory" SortExpression="Territory" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="column1" HeaderText="Mkt Segment" SortExpression="column1" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AR_Period" HeaderText="AR_Period" SortExpression="AR_Period" ReadOnly="True" Visible="false" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Revenue_Type" HeaderText="Revenue Type" SortExpression="Revenue_Type" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Service_Group" HeaderText="Service_Group" SortExpression="Service_Group" ReadOnly="True"  Visible="false"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Sfdc_Customer_Id" HeaderText="Sfdc Customer Id" SortExpression="Sfdc_Customer_Id" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Sfdc_Account_Owner_ID" HeaderText="Sfdc Owner ID" SortExpression="Sfdc_Account_Owner_ID" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Comments" HeaderText="Comments" SortExpression="Comments" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="SelectedRowStyle"/>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="Pager" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" CssClass="RowStyle" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <!-- <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" /> -->

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="BusinessSignUps" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BusinessSignUpsConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT ID, contact, week,year,[account_id], [product_name], [begin_date], [begin_request_date], [billing_country_code], [region], [billing_zip], [clear_name], [clear_lower_email], [Territory], [Market Segment] AS column1, [AR Period] AS AR_Period, [Revenue Type] AS Revenue_Type, [Service Group] AS Service_Group, [Sfdc Customer Id] AS Sfdc_Customer_Id, [Sfdc Account Owner ID] AS Sfdc_Account_Owner_ID,  [Comments] FROM [BusinessSignups]"
        UpdateCommand="Update [BusinessSignups] set contact = 'True' Where (ID = @ID)">
        <UpdateParameters>
             <asp:Parameter Name="contact" />
         </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('table .RowStyle input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled', 'true');
    });
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

the code behind

```
 Imports System.Data.SqlClient

 Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim cbSelect As Object

Private Property contacted As Object

   Protected Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 'Handles Button3.Click
    For Each gvRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows 'itterate tru all rows
        Dim chkBox As CheckBox = CType(gvRow.FindControl("cbSelect"), CheckBox) 'find the checkBox inside GridView

        Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection("Data Source=SYD-PB0FW9M\XXXXX;Initial Catalog=Support_Metrics;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXXXXX;Password=XXXXXXX")
        Dim sqlComm As New SqlCommand("update BusinessSignups set contacted=@cbSelect where ID='" & gvRow.Cells(0).Text & "'", sqlcon) 'this is an insert example, you can do update you can get the current gridView row id using gvRow.Cells(0).Text
        'Dim sqlComm As New SqlCommand("insert into BusinessSignups (contacted) values (@cbSelect)", sqlcon) 'this is an insert example, you can do update you can get the current gridView row id using gvRow.Cells(0).Text
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cbSelect", chkBox.Checked) 'passing the @cbSelect parameter to the command
        'sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int)
        Using (sqlcon)
            sqlcon.Open() 'open connection
            sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery() 'execute the command
        End Using
    Next
 End Sub

End Class
```

If I change the ASP connection string to be like the below the comments do save but then the update on the check box will not work...I can only have one or the other?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="BusinessSignUps" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BusinessSignUpsConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT ID, contact, week,year,[account_id], [product_name], [begin_date], [begin_request_date], [billing_country_code], [region], [billing_zip], [clear_name], [clear_lower_email], [Territory], [Market Segment] AS column1, [AR Period] AS AR_Period, [Revenue Type] AS Revenue_Type, [Service Group] AS Service_Group, [Sfdc Customer Id] AS Sfdc_Customer_Id, [Sfdc Account Owner ID] AS Sfdc_Account_Owner_ID,  [Comments] FROM [BusinessSignups]"
    UpdateCommand="Update [BusinessSignups] set Comments= @Comments Where (ID = @ID)">
    <UpdateParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="Comments" />
     </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
  <UpdateParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
  </UpdateParameters>
```

Comment: Tried this and it has not fixed the issue... I also noted that when I click on update it auto updates the tick box with out selecting it.

Comment: I see that the cbSelect is not bound to anything.

Comment: Why don't you bind the contact - as you have with the textbox and let the data grid handle the update for you in one go.  It seems like you are expecting the data grid to update the one value via a button, but the other via the normal process.   Sorry - but it could be I don't fully understand your requirement.